# how will be the lambda function with node.js will be for post request using the for application/x-www form-urlencoded data which stores to DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

```
var qs = require('qs')
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let body=qs.parse(event.body);
    console.log('passed',body);
    return{
        statusCode:300,
        body:JSON.stringify({
            message:'card added'
        })
    }
    }
```

i have this code,but it is not working with the url encoded function.

my ulrencoded data like

vtljson=[{
"name":"name"
"age":"age"
}]

this format i s a must,so i cant chnge the url-encoded format.how can i post this method to dynamodb thought lambda function using nonde.js code.

Comment: Your question needs to be rewritten to make it clear for others exactly what is going on. 

Try adding a section like this: "I run this code and I see X. I expect to see Y."

Comment: i just want to know how the data that posted to an api to be inserted to dynamodb.the format will be url encoded.i need that code with node.js

Comment: You are console.logging the body there, so you can see the payload that your handler receives. Do you mean that you want to make a call to the DynamoDB API in that handler and want to know how to encode the payload?